# Create ViewModel using multiple models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

Build ViewModel using two models

Model 1:  Person (Id,Name,Address,Phone,CategoryId)

Model 2: Category(CategoryId,CategoryText)

ViewModel: PersonViewModel (Name,Phone, CategoryText)

Question: how would I generate my ViewModel in my controller and forward it to the view:

```
 var model = (from x in db.Person 
             select new PersonViewModel { 
                    Name = x.Name, 
                    Phone = x.Phone, 
                    CategoryText = ??? }).ToList();
```

How do I generate CategoryText?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join on categories.
you may be able to include as the following, if not you just need a join. Try the following (I forget if you can include() in this syntax - somethingin my mind  tells me you can't and if that's the case I'll delete this shortly as I see someone just posted the join syntax)

```
var model = (from x in db.Person.Include(o=>o.Category) //assumes EF 4.1 if not try .Include("Category")
             select new PersonViewModel { 
                    Name = x.Name, 
                    Phone = x.Phone, 
                    CategoryText = x.Category.CategoryText }).ToList();
```

Comment: When I add the code CategoryText = x.Category.CategoryText. Category  not found. Do I need to modify Person Model to be able to access Category's CategoryText field?

Comment: It seems like I need to add: public virtual Category Category { get; set; } in the Person model and it works by accessing  x.Category.CategoryText.
> I also noticed if add "Include(o=>o.Category)" or "not", it still works and in the sql Profiler the generated query is the same, then why do I need to add" Include(o=>o.Category)" in the query? Plz explain it to me. thx!

Comment: because the lazy loading is forcing the join here. It isn't always like that (but does in your case because you call .ToList() and your context hasn't yet been disposed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: thanks Adam, plz clarify if I am correct. If I wanted to use your logic (eagar loading) to retrieve the data since it does single request against the database. I would remove ToList() from generating the query and modify my model (person) to public Category Category { get; set; }, removing the virtual keyword? correct?

Comment: not sure if you do/dont have to remove virtual there, but you definitely want to keep the ToList() as that forces the load.

Answer (score 1):

```
var model = (from x in db.Person
             join y from db.Category on x.CategoryId equals y.CategoryID 
             select new PersonViewModel { 
                    Name = x.Name, 
                    Phone = x.Phone, 
                    CategoryText = y.CategoryText }).ToList();
```